# Текст по центру

Tags: html, css

HTML код:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="70">
            <div id="circle">
                Q
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS код:

```
#circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #7e8e9f;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

По коду видно, что я рисую окружность. Необходимо в этой окружности вывести текст, который будет в центре окружности. Как сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с line-height

```css
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #7e8e9f;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="70">
      <div id="circle">Q</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вариант с псевдоэлементом

```css
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7e8e9f;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#circle:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="70">
      <div id="circle">Q</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно с `display:flex`:

```css
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #7e8e9f;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th width="70">
      <div id="circle">
        Q
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```